# Не происходит конвертация футов в метры. Помогите разобраться в чем моя ошибка

Tags: golang

```
package main 

import "fmt"

func main() {
     fmt.Print("Enter a value foot:")
     var foot float64
     fmt.Scanf("%f,&foot")

     meters:= foot/3.2808

     fmt.Println("in meters:", meters)
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не происходит"? Что выдается на выходе и чем это не устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этой строке `fmt.Scanf("%f,&foot")`
там кавычки поехали:)

Исправляем

```
fmt.Scanf("%f",&foot)
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил кавычки все работает:)

Comment: (обычно тут нажимают на стрелочку вверх, если все ок, @DimaTverdokhlebov )